# Wordpress Multisite - pay to create blog

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Hoping someone can help, I've searched everywhere for a Wordpress plugin that will enable me to charge users to create multisite blogs, i.e. on creation of a new multisite blog, via the wp-signup.php page, blog creators are charged a fee, say $5.

I've looked at various membership plugins to do this but can't find one that simply and logically does the above. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Membership Pro doesn't do the job, actually.

You'll want this plugin for what you're trying to do: https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/pro-sites/?npp=b&utm_expid=3606929-81.6_x2aktJQ2qbOSnTRGna0w.1#ref

Answer (score 0):

You can create multisite in wordpress and you can charge for registration. Here is a good post on how to do that.

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-edublogs-org-site-in-7-easy-steps/

It obviously is not as simple, you will need some good knowledge of wordpress and some modifications to make it work to your needs. "Membership Pro" is a good plugin to start with.